# Meteor, how to browser tab select events?

Tags: events, meteor

```
Template.temp.events({
 "focusOut window" : function(){
  console.log('exit window')
 }
});
```

Like this `focusOut` window trigger code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work as the template will only list to dom events inside its own scope.

Better to handle this using jquery and setup an event listener when the template is rendered.

```
Template.temp.onRendered(function() {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
       $(window).blur(function() {
          // Do something here....
          $("title").text("Don't forget to read this..." + pageTitle);
       });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Something along these lines should work, its fragile... and may need some tweaking, but this should get you started.